# Increase Poké Miles yield from Streetpass?

Tags: pokemon-x-y, streetpass

What determines how many Poké Miles you earn from Streetpasses, and is it possible to increase it?

I ask because I always only earn a single Poké Mile per hit, which seems hilariously low considering any kind of online interaction yields far, far higher numbers - I think a single Wonder Trade yields about 40. It's not even worth bothering checking the Streetpass data for: I have ~13,000 Poké Miles in total, of which only about 10 were gained through Streetpass. Granted, I Wonder Trade *a lot*, but that's still a ridiculous ratio.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Pokemiles are calculated by the distance between your home location and the other player's home location. So by Streetpass, you're mostly getting people from...basically 0 miles away.

Streetpass is generally pretty useless for Pokemon XY for this reason, and I would personally suggest ignoring it. If you want more, you could make sure to walk/drive past Streetpass relays, but your time would be much better spent simply wondertrading a few pokemon to get the Pokemiles. Since a good percentage of wondertrades are from Japan and the US, which are of course a good distance away, wondertrading will very often yield a fair number of miles.

Comment: Ah, that's interesting, hadn't realised it was related to distance. And yeah, I wonder trade all the time (over 200 trades so far!). Heck of a good way to get rid of the "spares" of whatever I've been breeding lately.

Comment: @Kai yeah the distance factor is neat, but it basically means if you're in the US you get no points unless you trade with Japanese players (or the relatively few who play in another non JP/NA region)

Comment: If you are planning a trip to a popular tourist location (for foreign tourists, like Washington, DC), if you carry your 3ds in your pocket, you will likely see many street passes from other countries (before x&y, I went to Washington DC and opened many new countries on the streetpass plaza map, so I believe this would be "Super Effective" for pokemiles too)