# How many Pokemiles does each method earn?

Tags: pokemon-x-y

I want to farm PokeMiles so I can purchase bulk PP Ups and Rare Candies. I understand that every 1,000 in game steps will earn you one PokeMile, but what about all of the other ways?

The other methods include: Trading, Battling, and Streetpass.

Comment: In-game, these are earned by doing a variety of things including trading Pokémon on the GTS, StreetPassing other players, making Wonder Trades and just standard trading. In addition to that, you have the ability to play attractions on the Pokémon Global Link in order to earn PokéMiles.

Comment: I understand how to get them, I'm trying to figure out what the most effective method for farming them is. Would it be faster to just get them via steps, or would I be better off wonder trading non-stop? I'll reword the question so I can get an answer I can work with.

Comment: What I used to do was get one Pokemon that I didn't care for and Wonder Trade it... take that traded Pokemon and WT it again, over and over again. If you can get them just by walking around, you can setup your DS to auto walk/bike for you around the Lumiose tower all day when you aren't home or at night when you're sleeping. I've done this before raising Pokemon levels in the daycare. Leave your charger plugged in, your DS on, and put something on the left or right arrow to hold it down and you'll rack up the steps quickly.

Comment: Ok not on the arrows but on the circle pad, put a little piece of paper underneath it to hold it right or left. Here's a video demonstrating it: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OBKhPHrLa0Y

Comment: @C-dizzle I would do the walking technique, but the circle part of the circle pad on my DS broke off a while ago. I planned on using the Prism Tower Circle to farm them.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### **Wonder Trade**

According to [Bulbapedia](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Wonder_Trade):

> Wonder Trading will give the player Poké Miles depending on how far the other player Wonder Trading with them is from their location; the farther the other player, the more Poké Miles will be earned.

I live in Italy, and if I trade with another Italian player I will get a bunch of 10 or less Poke Miles per trade. However, a trade with someone really far (Japanese players for me) can give you a hundred of Pokemiles, more or less.

#### **Streetpass**

Poke Miles are calculated by the distance between your home location and the other player's home location. So by Streetpass, you're mostly getting people from basically 0 miles away.

Streetpass is generally pretty useless for Pokemon XY for this reason, and I would personally suggest ignoring it. If you want more, you could make sure to walk/drive past Streetpass relays, but your time would be much better spent simply wondertrading a few pokemon to get the Pokemiles. Since a good percentage of wondertrades are from Japan and the US, which are of course a good distance away, wondertrading will very often yield a fair number of miles.

If you are planning a trip to a popular tourist location, if you carry your 3DS in your pocket, you will likely see many Streetpasses from other countries (this could be "Super Effective" for pokemiles too).

Source, [this answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/139135/87579).

I think this should be true for **online battles**, too.

#### Pokebank

> [Poké Miles](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Pok%C3%A9_Mile) can also be earned by storing Pokémon in Pokémon Bank.
>
> Poké Miles are awarded for the length of time that a given Pokémon is deposited into [Pokémon Bank](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Pok%C3%A9mon_Bank#Rewards). The amount of Poké Miles earned by the player increases if more Pokémon are deposited into Pokémon Bank.

This is actually another good way to farm Poke Miles, the more Pokemon you store on the Bank, the more Poke Miles you get.
You can easily get about 1000 Poke Miles every month, just with a bunch of full boxes.

Comment: So, in this sense, Pokemiles are 1 for 1 with how many miles away the person you are interacting with? Or do you just get more based off of distance.

Comment: @ShadowZ. I think they're something like 1 Pokemile each 100 km of distance with the person you're interacting with, more or less.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure you get Pokemiles for trading with people across the world. So trade with people from different continents, I suppose